# Python - Generating RSS with PyRSS2Gen

Tags: python, xml, module

I'm attempting to write a program that utilizes urllib2 to parse HTML, and then utilizes PyRSS2Gen to create the RSS feed, in XML.

I keep getting the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pythonproject.py", line 46, in <module>
    get_rss()
  File "pythonproject.py", line 43, in get_rss
    rss.write_xml(open("cssnews.rss.xml", "w"))
  File "build/lib/PyRSS2Gen.py", line 34, in write_xml
    self.publish(handler)
  File "build/lib/PyRSS2Gen.py", line 380, in publish
    item.publish(handler)
  File "build/lib/PyRSS2Gen.py", line 427, in publish
    _opt_element(handler, "title", self.title)
  File "build/lib/PyRSS2Gen.py", line 58, in _opt_element
    _element(handler, name, obj)
  File "build/lib/PyRSS2Gen.py", line 53, in _element
    obj.publish(handler)
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'publish'
```

upon trying to run it.

From what I could find, other users came across this issue when trying to create a new tag for the XML, but I am trying to use the default tags given with PyRSS2Gen. Inspecting the PyRSS2Gen.py file shows the write_xml() command I am using, so is the error with how I am assigning values to the rss items by popping them from a list?

```
def get_rss():
    sys.path.append('build/lib')
    from PyRSS2Gen import RSS2, RSSItem

    rss = RSS2(
        title = 'Python RSS Creator',
        link = 'technews.acm.org',
        description = 'Creates RSS out of HTML',
        items = [],
    )

    for x in range(0, len(rssTitles)):
        rss.items.append(RSSItem(
            title = rssTitles.pop,
            link = rssLinks.pop,
            description = rssDesc.pop,
        ))

    rss.write_xml(open("cssnews.rss.xml", "w"))

# 5 - Call function
get_rss()
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just writing out to a file, like so;

```
news = open("news.rss.xml", "w")
news.write("<?xml version=\"1.0\" ?>")
news.write("\n")
news.write("<rss xmlns:atom=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom\" version=\"2.0\">")
news.write("\n")
news.write("<channel>")
news.write("\n")
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

PyRSS2Gen relies on its inputs to either be strings or to have a publish method that does all the necessary conversion.

In this case, you missed to call the pop method on the rssTitles, giving you a function rather than a string. Adding `()` after all the pop mentions should give you a usable program.

Note that similar errors can also crop up when there's other non-sting items around (eg. byte strings); the AttributeError line gives you a hint as to the object that went into the RSS item, and the backtrace indicates where in the RSS item that is (the title, in this case).